# Workaround for alert fail to disconnect Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bdd

I am automating an website using JBehave and Selenium Webdriver, one of the functionality is to logout the system.
It works for most times, but eventually it doesn't, because the browser shows an alert saying: "Fail to disconnect" and it throws the following exception:

org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you get a "Fail to disconnect" alert? Would a real user get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the Alert first and then accept or dismiss it.

Try this-

```
        IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();

        //Accept Alert 
        alert.Accept();

        //Or

        //Dismiss Alert 
        alert.Dismiss();
```